# Why are channel addresses IP the same,How to display the real address

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ 3.5.0, Erlang 19.0

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxe09.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That IP is the IP assigned to the machine in the internal network that connects to rabbitmq. They all have the same IP because all channels reside on the same machine, and they open different ports.

If by "real address" you mean the external IP, if both the server and  the clients are in a private network, the external IP is never used, so it will not be seen.

Comment: How should I locate which client

Comment: every connection will have a name and an IP, based on that you can tell. using the IP you can ping it in your network and find the machine